# pasar varios parametros de sqlDataSource a un stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado que hace un select a una tabla segun varios criterios, es un tipo busqueda si el usuario no ingresa ningun parametro se deben mostrar todos los registros de la tabla, en caso de que el usuario decida rellenar un criterio de busqueda solo regresa los registros que coinciden

```sql
USE [aaa]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcListarAnunciosPortal]
    (
    @ID_Anuncio BIGINT =NULL ,
    @Icono VARCHAR(30) =NULL ,
    @Titulo VARCHAR(200) =NULL ,
    @Cuerpo VARCHAR(Max) =NULL ,
    @UrlArchivo VARCHAR(255) =NULL ,
    @PaginaPrincipal BIT =NULL ,
    @FechaDesde DATE =NULL ,
    @FechaHasta DATE =NULL ,
    @ID_UsuarioAlta INT =NULL ,
    @FechaAlta DATETIME =NULL ,
    @ID_UsuarioModifica INT =NULL ,
    @FechaModificacion DATETIME =NULL 
    )
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    BEGIN TRY
    SELECT 
        ID_Anuncio,
        Icono,
        Titulo,
        Cuerpo,
        UrlArchivo,
        PaginaPrincipal,
        FechaDesde,
        FechaHasta,
        ID_UsuarioAlta,
        FechaAlta,
        ID_UsuarioModifica,
        FechaModificacion
 FROM ANUNCIOSPORTAL    WHERE 
        (ID_Anuncio=@ID_Anuncio OR @ID_Anuncio IS NULL) AND 
        (Icono=@Icono OR @Icono IS NULL) AND 
        (Titulo=@Titulo OR @Titulo IS NULL) AND 
        (Cuerpo=@Cuerpo OR @Cuerpo IS NULL) AND 
        (UrlArchivo=@UrlArchivo OR @UrlArchivo IS NULL) AND 
        (PaginaPrincipal=@PaginaPrincipal OR @PaginaPrincipal IS NULL) AND 
        (FechaDesde=@FechaDesde OR @FechaDesde IS NULL) AND 
        (FechaHasta=@FechaHasta OR @FechaHasta IS NULL) AND 
        (ID_UsuarioAlta=@ID_UsuarioAlta OR @ID_UsuarioAlta IS NULL) AND 
        (FechaAlta=@FechaAlta OR @FechaAlta IS NULL) AND 
        (ID_UsuarioModifica=@ID_UsuarioModifica OR @ID_UsuarioModifica IS NULL) AND 
        (FechaModificacion=@FechaModificacion OR @FechaModificacion IS NULL) AND 
        (Eliminado <> 1)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        EXEC ProcMensajeError 
    END CATCH
END
```

estoy usando para esto un sqlDataSource pero tengo problemas cuando quiero enviar los criterios de busqueda vacios para que me regrese todos los registros de la tabla, este es mi script en la pagina aspx:

```
<asp:GridView DataKeyNames="ID_Anuncio" SkinID="gridGeneral" DataSourceID="sqlAnunciosPortal"
       AllowSorting="True" ID="gvAnuncios" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
       ForeColor="Black" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" EmptyDataText="No se encontraron resultados..."
       Visible="False" PageSize="15" >
       <Columns>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="ID_Anuncio" SortExpression="ID_Anuncio" HeaderText="Id">
                   <ItemStyle Wrap="False" Width="80px" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
             </asp:BoundField>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="Titulo" HeaderText="Titulo" SortExpression="Titulo">
                   <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
             </asp:BoundField>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="Cuerpo" HeaderText="Cuerpo" SortExpression="Cuerpo">
                   <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
             </asp:BoundField>
             <asp:TemplateField>
                   <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:ImageButton ID="BtnEditar" runat="server" PostBackUrl="DatosProfesion.aspx"
                                        ImageUrl="~/Images/editar.png" AlternateText="Editar" ToolTip="Editar"
                                        CommandName="2" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID_Anuncio") %>' />
                   </ItemTemplate>
                   <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Top" />
             </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField>
                   <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:ImageButton ID="BtnEliminar" runat="server" PostBackUrl="DatosProfesion.aspx"
                                        ImageUrl="~/Images/eliminar.png" AlternateText="Eliminar" ToolTip="Eliminar"
                                        CommandName="3" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID_Anuncio") %>' />
                   </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <SelectedRowStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" CssClass="Green" BackColor="Yellow" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlAnunciosPortal" runat="server" SelectCommand="ProcListarAnunciosPortal" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
             <asp:Parameter Name="ID_Anuncio" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
             <asp:Parameter Name="Titulo" Type="String" DefaultValue="" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
             <asp:Parameter Name="FechaDesde" Type="String" DefaultValue="" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
             <asp:Parameter Name="FechaHasta" Type="String" DefaultValue="" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
        </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

y en mi codebehind:

```
protected void BtnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)     
{
     try
     {
            this.sqlAnunciosPortal.SelectParameters["ID_Anuncio"].DefaultValue = this.txtIdAnuncio.Text.Trim();
            this.sqlAnunciosPortal.SelectParameters["Titulo"].DefaultValue = this.txtTitulo.Text.Trim();
            this.sqlAnunciosPortal.SelectParameters["FechaDesde"].DefaultValue = this.txtFechaI.Text.Trim();
            this.sqlAnunciosPortal.SelectParameters["FechaHasta"].DefaultValue = this.txtFechaF.Text.Trim();

            this.gvAnuncios.DataBind();
            this.gvAnuncios.Visible = true;
     }
     catch (Exception exc)
     { 
            this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "Script", Util.Alert(exc.Message.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\t", "").Replace("'", ""))); }
     }
}
```

realmente no se que estoy haciendo mal, ya que cuando intento enviar varios parámetros como esta en el código de arriba no me muestra nada en mi GridView y si dejo solo el primer parámetro que  es ID_Anuncio si me muestra el registro coincidente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solucion fue que no se estaban enviando los datos como null como lo requiere el SP, solo coloque una condicion cuando se reciben los datos en el code behind

```html
            this.sqlAnunciosPortal.SelectParameters["Titulo"].DefaultValue = txtTitulo.Text.Trim() == "" ? null : txtTitulo.Text.Trim();
            this.sqlAnunciosPortal.SelectParameters["FechaDesde"].DefaultValue = txtFechaI.Text.Trim() == "" ? null : txtFechaI.Text.Trim();
            this.sqlAnunciosPortal.SelectParameters["FechaHasta"].DefaultValue = txtFechaF.Text.Trim() == "" ? null : txtFechaF.Text.Trim();
            this.sqlAnunciosPortal.CancelSelectOnNullParameter = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Es un poco complejo seguirlo todo, pero sospecho que tu problema es por los parámetros `FechaDesde` y `FechaHasta`. Tu procedimiento almacenado espera `DATETIME`, y tu le estas pasando strings.

En primer lugar, debes cambiar el tipo de tus parámetros:

```
<asp:Parameter Name="FechaDesde" Type="DateTime"/>
<asp:Parameter Name="FechaHasta" Type="DateTime"/>
```

Y luego convertir tus fechas a `DateTime` al darle valor a los parámetros:

```
this.sqlAnunciosPortal.SelectParameters["FechaDesde"].DefaultValue = DateTime.Parse(this.txtFechaI.Text.Trim());
this.sqlAnunciosPortal.SelectParameters["FechaHasta"].DefaultValue = DateTime.Parse(this.txtFechaF.Text.Trim());
```

Comment: me marca esto: cannot implicitly convert type system.datetime to string

Comment: ya publique la solución solo que necesito que alguien la coloque como respuesta ya que yo no puedo

Comment: Que tal @Ivxn, ¿has intentado realizar un query dinámico? o ¿tienes idea de que es un query dinámico?

Comment: @JulioMorenoDev no he usado querys dinamicos :(